# Defference between $\delta(|\boldsymbol{r}| - 1)$ and $\chi_{S^{2}}(\boldsymbol{r})$ in three-dimensional integration

Tags: integration, measure-theory, 3d

Are the following equations incorrect?
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}} f(\boldsymbol{r})\delta(|\boldsymbol{r}| - 1) \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r} = \int_{S^{2}} f(\boldsymbol{r}) \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r} \tag{1},
$$
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}} f(\boldsymbol{r})\chi_{S^{2}}(\boldsymbol{r}) \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r} = \int_{S^{2}} f(\boldsymbol{r}) \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r} \tag{2},
$$
where $\delta$ is Dirac's delta and $\chi_{\Omega}$ is characteristic function with support $\Omega$.
If these are correct, it makes me wonder.

Comment: How can the integral be over $\mathbb R^3$ and only have $dr$ term ?

Comment: @P.Quinton Sorry for the confusion. $\boldsymbol{r}$ is a vector.

Comment: In order to compute the first one, you have to go to polar coordinate (therefore multiply by the radius), then you can simplify the dirak delta, the mulitplicative radius term is $1$ and then transform back to cartesian coordinate (divide by the radius, which is $1$) and you obtain the first equation. The second one is obvious, so yes I think they are the same.

Comment: @P.Quinton Thank you for sharing your opinion!